# Is $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ an irreducible representation of $O(n, \mathbb{C})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, orthogonal-matrices, classical-groups

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is an irreducible representation of $O(n, \mathbb{C}) = \left\{ A \in GL(n) | A^{t}A = Id \right\}$. I presume the action is defined in the standard way, i.e. $g \cdot v = gv$ with $g \in O(n)$ and $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$. I could not think of anything different from applying the definition, thus proving there is no proper submodule of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Thus, by contradiction, I was trying to prove that if $A$ is a proper submodule and $v \in \mathbb{C}^n \setminus A$, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $B$ such that $Bv \notin A$. However, I don’t think I have enough information to conclude the existence of $B$. Is this even the right approach?

As a related question, once I will have proven that $O(n, \mathbb{C})$ is irreducible, I was asked to use this information to prove that $O(n, \mathbb{C})$ generates $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as an algebra, but I don’t really know how: $O(n)$ is an algebraic linear group, so in what sense does a group generate an algebra? Is it in the sense of vector spaces in this case?

Comment: For the first question: show that for any vector $v$, there are (very simple and real) orthogonal matrices $A,B$ such that $w=Av+Bv$ has a single nonzero component. Deduce that the canonical basis is spanned by some $Cw$ where $C$ are (real and simple again) orthogonal matrices.

Comment: For $n=2$, I figured $A=Id$, $B= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, $C= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Is this correct? (If it is, matrices can easily be generalised for $n > 2$

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly it.

Comment: @Mindlack thanks. Does the same trick work to prove that $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ is an irreducible representation of $Sp(2n, \mathbb{C})$? I tried by choosing $A= Id$ and $B= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ , but I have trouble finding $C$: do we need another strategy here?